# If statement not judgind correctly

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement, declaration

I am working with arrays now and the IF statement is judging wrong. I resumed my code:

```
Sub Reset()
Nr=6
Dim X, Y, MinX, AM, NX, W As Double
Y=200,00
AM=5,00
ReDim X(Nr)
ReDim Z(Nr)

For i = 1 To Nr
     X(i - 1) = Y - WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, LTi.Column + i - 1), .Cells(10, 2 + i - 1)))
     Z(i - 1) = X(i - 1)
     W(i - 1) = 0
     NX(i - 1) = X(i - 1)
Next i

MinX = Format(Application.Min(X), "0.00")
' MinX =10 in my case
If MinX >= AM Then
    'code 1
End If

If MinX < AM Then
    'code 2
end if
end sub
```

The Problem is that MinX is > than AM and it is not going into the first IF statement (code 1), but in the second. I do not know if I decalred the variables correctly, or something else.
If MinX is < AM, it ins going into the second statement as well (code 2).

Could please someone help me? I am more than weeks in this issue...
Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where values are added to the array named `X`, which means `MinX` = `"0.00"`, which is definitely less than 5.  Where are you adding values to `X`?  Did you leave that section out of the code you posted?

Comment: Is this line `(i - 1) = Y - WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, LTi.Column + i - 1), .Cells(10, 2 + i - 1)))` supposed to have `X` in it: `X(i - 1) = Y - WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, LTi.Column + i - 1), .Cells(10, 2 + i - 1)))`?

Comment: That row neither makes sense nor does it compile...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for coment.
I wrote wrong a lot of things, 
Sub Reset()
Nr=6
Dim X, Y, MinX, AM, NX, W As Double
Y=200,00
AM=5,00
ReDim X(Nr)
ReDim Z(Nr)

For i = 1 To NrParcelas
     X(i - 1) = Y - WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, LTi.Column + i - 1), .Cells(10, 2 + i - 1)))
     Z(i - 1) = X(i - 1)
     W(i - 1) = 0
     NX(i - 1) = X(i - 1)
Next i

MinX = Format(Application.Min(X), "0.00")
' MinX =10 in my case and AM=5,00
If MinX >= AM Then
    'code 1
End If

If MinX < AM Then
    'code 2
end if
end sub

So, it should go to "code 1" but it is going to "code 2"

Comment: Could you correct the code in the question (edit the question, don't post it as comment, it's unreadable) so that it is complete and compiles. The number constants uses an invalid syntax, the `.Range`-part will not compile as you don't use a `With`-statement. `NrParcelas` is not defined in your code, `W` and `NX` are  not arrays...

Comment: That said: Your problem is likely because you declare `MinX` as Variant and assign a string to it when using `Format` and therefore the IF-statement will compare strings, not numbers

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks. But I have to limit the number of decimal places (max 2), how should I do it?

Answer (score 3):

So, as written in the comments, there are quite some issues with the code so that it will neither compile nor run.

Assuming that you don't show your complete code and your real code at least is executable:

**a)** In VBA, you need to specify the type for every variable explicitly, else you will declare them as `Variant`. Your declaration should be

```
Dim X as Double, Y as Double, MinX as Double, AM as Double, NX as Double, W As Double
```

With your declaration, only `W` is declared as Double, all other variables are declared as Variant which mean they can contain *anything* - a double, a string, a boolean, an object reference and many more.

**b)** You use `Format` to assign the calculated value of the `Min`-function to the variable `MinX`. [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) is used to *format* a number or date into a String following the format-pattern you provide. You format the *numeric* value `10` to a *string* containing the characters `1` `0` `.` `0` `0` (as `MinX` is a Variant, it can countain a string).

Now you use that string and compare it with the number stored in `AM` which is  `5`. As you can't compare a string and a number, VBA converts the number implicitly into a string containing the character `5`. As `5` has a higher Ascii value than `1`, your code will skip the first `If` and hit the second.

If you want to round a numeric value, simply use the [round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function)-function:

```
MinX = round(Application.Min(X), 2)
```

With that line, MinX is a number, rounded to 2 decimals and the `If` will compare the *numeric values* of `MinX` and `AM` and it will hit the first `If`.

Comment: Just as side note: `VBA.Round` and `WorksheetFunction.Round` do not perform the same operation. 
[`VBA.Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function)
 - other than the tabular Excel form - uses so called *bankers' rounding* 
(i.e. midpoint value 5 always rounding to the nearest even number). This is a standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical operations 
in order to minimize significant rounding errors over multiple rounding operations 
by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction.